# How to customize android studio template?

Tags: android

I am an Android developer which is using Android Studio3.0.I should say it is a powerful tool but when I create a new project and I select the checkbox to generate layout it always does generate the constraint layout for me.But I do not need this. In most times, I need the relative layout as my base layout for the whole layout. How to customize the template? Can anyone offer some tips or solutions? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: *Can anyone offer some tips* you might not want to hear it, but start using constraintlayout

Comment: @TimCastelijns, that is your opinion, which I don't agree with. Especially for beginners, `ConstraintLayout` is something too advanced.

Comment: constraintlayout is not advanced. I would argue that it is even easier for new developers to learn that, than to learn RL and LL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should edit `ftl` files in Android Studio.
The `ftl` file is a kind of placeholder specification used in Android Studio (and JetBrains products)

Open Android Studio location. in my case, it is in `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`, and go deep to `\plugins\android\lib\templates` location.

At the location, you can read which directories are actually reflected to Android Studio template wizard window.

Open one of them, for example, `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities\TabbedActivity\root\res\layout` and you will see

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}$PlaceholderFragment">

...

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now, edit `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` to what you want, and Save. You might need to restart Android Studio in order to read template again.

Detail information can be found at here: https://coderwall.com/p/fsxvyw/file-templates-in-android-studio